# Populate complex SQL Database with python via reflection?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a relatively complex MySQL Database (60+ Tables) that I need to populate regularly. There are a lot of foreign key constraints on most of the tables. I started writing my import engine using SQL Alchemy.

Do I need to reconstruct my entire Database with SQL Alchemy classes in order to do this? Does anyone have any better suggestions? Only 8 of the tables actually accept new raw data, the rest are populated from these tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLAlchemy reflection to create the classes mapped to MySQL table structure. See [Reflecting Database Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/reflection.html). There is a subchapter there showing how to reflect all tables (Reflecting Database Objects).

Code copied from the above link to reflect one table:

```
messages = Table('messages', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

All tables:

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=someengine)
users_table = meta.tables['users']
addresses_table = meta.tables['addresses']
```